What kind of IC is this - damaged in the TQFN10 housing, marking WEA
I have a problem with HMI Allen Bradley,
The ETHERNET port does not work, I found out that this area is powered by an IC in the TQFN10 housing with the code WEA.
What kind of arrangement is this?


The pads near that IC look a bit like they're corroded. Did the board get wet?

It's probably a Microchip MIC23153YMT-TR step-down converter.

As far as I can tell, the product code isn't specified in the datasheet, but the picture on lcsc shows WEA:

(source: lcsc.com)
